# CTreeCtrl expand and collapse icons not working

Tags: mfc

I have created class inherit from CtreeCtrl name CMytreeCtrl in mfc visual studio 2010 professional edition
    CMytreeCtrl obTreeCtrl;
I would like to display different icon , when expanding a particular node as follows:-

```
m_imageList.Create (16, 16, ILC_COLOR32, 1,4);   
m_bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP5);

m_imageList.Add(&m_bitmap, RGB(255,0,255));
SetImageList (&m_imageList, TVSIL_NORMAL);

SetItemImage(hTreeItemRoot,0,0);//parent node
SetItemImage(hTreeItem,1,2) // child node
```

So if I expand the child node image index no 2 is used for selected image index otherwise image index no 1 is displayed. I am able to display icon no 1 in normal state, but when I exand the same treeItem, it is not changing the icon.

Comment: Your image list has a single entry. Why do you expect non-existant images at indices 1 or 2 to show?

Comment: I corrected that mistake, now Please suggest me the reason to fix my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the icon of the tree item, you need to setup at least 2 icons on your **CImageList**.

```
MyTreeCtrl.SetItemImage(hItem, 0, 0);  // for first icon
MyTreeCtrl.SetItemImage(hAnotherItem, 1, 1);  // for second icon
```

and the place where you setup this is reflection of **TVN_ITEMEXPANDED** message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-itemexpanded

Comment: Flaviu2:- I need to set icon for the same hItem, but you are setting for different nodes of Tree?

Comment: I am able to solve the problem by handling TVN_ITEMEXPANDED
Thanks Flaviu2